# Publishing quality graphs to Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: graphics, export

I am trying to produce publishing quality graphs. I would like to export graphs from a Notebook to Ai (Adobe Illustrator). How do I do this? Just started using Mathematica, very new!

Thanks,
Anousheh

PS This is NOT a duplicate question!!! It has nothing to do with the FONTS!!!

A simple question of how to export graphs into Ai.

Can we attache files (Notebooks) for easiness?

Thank you,
Anousheh

Comment: Try export as eps or pdf.  AI should be able to import those formats.

Comment: You need to export to a format that Illustrator is able to read.  Check the docs on `Export` on how to export graphics, and choose a format that Illustrator understand.  As Sjoerd said, EPS and PDF are the best choice.

Comment: Hello, Thank you Sjoerd and Szabolcs.

Comment: The duplicate part is about using EPS to get Mathematica plots into Illustrator. That was already mentioned in the other question. The font problem is indeed an additional problem, but also something you may suffer from after using EPS for exports to AI.